# What is the standard practice while inserting data into Cassandra Tables?

Tags: cassandra

What is the standard practice while inserting data into Cassandra Tables?? Can we use lowercase/uppercase /camelcase ??

example : insert into test  (a, b) values ( 'foo' ,'bar'); or
       insert into test (a, b) values ('FOO' ,'BAR');

Comment: I don't think that there is a standard practice for DATA. Its a decision to be made by the users.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard way for your example. The values 'foo' and 'FOO' are different values.

I prefer writing uppercase cql (or sql) for better readability, but thats no standard at all.

```
INSERT INTO test (a, b) VALUES ('foo', 'bar');
```